Efficiently reparsing string series (in a dataframe) into a struct, recasting the fields of the struct and then unnesting it
Consider the following toy example:
import polars as pl

xs = pl.DataFrame(
    [
        pl.Series(
            "date",
            ["2024 Jan", "2024 Feb", "2024 Jan", "2024 Jan"],
            dtype=pl.String,
        )
    ]
)
ys = (
    xs.with_columns(
        pl.col("date").str.split(" ").list.to_struct(fields=["year", "month"]),
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("date").struct.with_fields(pl.field("year").cast(pl.Int16()))
    )
    .unnest("date")
)
ys

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ year ┆ month │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i16  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
│ 2024 ┆ Feb   │
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
└──────┴───────┘

I think it would be more efficient to do the operations on a unique series of date data (I could use replace, but I have opted for join for no good reason):
unique_dates = (
    pl.DataFrame([xs["date"].unique()])
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("date")
        .str.split(" ")
        .list.to_struct(fields=["year", "month"])
        .alias("struct_date")
    )
    .with_columns(
        pl.col("struct_date").struct.with_fields(
            pl.field("year").cast(pl.Int16())
        )
    )
)
unique_dates

shape: (2, 2)
┌──────────┬──────────────┐
│ date     ┆ struct_date  │
│ ---      ┆ ---          │
│ str      ┆ struct[2]    │
╞══════════╪══════════════╡
│ 2024 Jan ┆ {2024,"Jan"} │
│ 2024 Feb ┆ {2024,"Feb"} │
└──────────┴──────────────┘

zs = (
    xs.join(unique_dates, on="date", left_on="date", right_on="struct_date")
    .drop("date")
    .rename({"struct_date": "date"})
    .unnest("date")
)

zs

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ year ┆ month │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i16  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
│ 2024 ┆ Feb   │
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
└──────┴───────┘

What can I do to improve the efficiency of this operation even further? Am I using polars idiomatically enough?

Turning the String column into a Categorial would probably make the join at the end a lot faster.

.str.splitn() should be more efficient as it avoids the List creation + .list.to_struct()
.struct.field() can also be used to "unnest" the fields directly.
xs.select(
    pl.col.date.str.splitn(" ", 2)
      .struct.rename_fields(["year", "month"])
      .struct.with_fields(pl.field("year").cast(pl.Int16))
      .struct.field("year", "month")
)

shape: (4, 2)
┌──────┬───────┐
│ year ┆ month │
│ ---  ┆ ---   │
│ i16  ┆ str   │
╞══════╪═══════╡
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
│ 2024 ┆ Feb   │
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
│ 2024 ┆ Jan   │
└──────┴───────┘


What about turning the strings into a categorical?

@bzm3r For what purpose?

@bzm3r If this is related to your other questions: you should ask a question with the starting raw text and show the final desired output - explaining the actual task in full. The approaches used in your previous questions are not "efficient" (i.e. iteratively building numpy arrays / arrow table / unpivoting) If you give the full details, it will be much easier for people to help with an efficient approach. (e.g. it's likely much faster to do the regex matching directly in Polars/DuckDB, using the Lazy API, etc.)

It's not related to my other questions. I just use the same toy examples repeatedly, as I attempt to orient myself around the ecosystem.
I ask about turning the strings into a categorical, because BallpointBen says in comments above: "Turning the String column into a Categorial would probably make the join at the end a lot faster."

Ah okay. Perhaps I'm wrong, but I don't see how using Categoricals would fit into the splitn approach.
